# Is allocating a dynamic array without specifying size well formed code?

Tags: c++, new-operator, language-lawyer

The following simple program snippet gives compilation errors with `gcc-4.3.4`.

**Program:**

```
int main() 
{   
    char *ptr = new char[10];     
    char *ptr1 = new char[];      
    return 0; 
}
```

**Compilation errors:**

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:4: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
>   prog.cpp:3: warning: unused variable ‘ptr’
>   prog.cpp:4: warning: unused variable ‘ptr1’

But the same compiles cleanly with MSVC without any diagnostic message.

So my question is:
Does the Standard allow an `new []` to be called without specifying the `size`? Or this a bug in MSVC?
Can someone provide a reference from the standard which will conclusively say that the above code example is ill-formed or well-formed?

---

I have had a look at:

**5.3.4 New [expr.new]** &
**18.4.1.2 Array forms [lib.new.delete.array]**

but couldnt find any conclusive evidence about the behavior.

---

**EDIT:**
Adding the `Language Lawyer` tag.
I am expecting the answer for an observed behavior regardless of whether it is useful or not, I am fully aware it is not useful nor recommended.

Comment: If it's legal I don't see the point of it...

Comment: I don't see how it could be well formed code?  What is the compiler going to do, guess the size?  That seems rather difficult (if not impossible).

Comment: +1, interesting, waiting for a good answer.

Comment: does `new char[]` allocate memory? i think it creates only a pointer

Answer (score 4):

This is not syntactically correct.

Have a look at the [syntax](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#new-expression) for a *new-expression*.

A *noptr-new-declarator* must contain an *expression* between the square brackets, and an *expression* must have a token in it.

Answer (score 4):

That is not legal c++.

5.3.4 New [expr.new] shows what are legal ways to call new in a big list, which contains this line :

```
noptr-new-declarator:
        [ expression ] attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt
        noptr-new-declarator [ constant-expression ] attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt
```

and later it explains what the constant-expression can be (in 5.4.3/6 and 5.4.3/7) :

> Every constant-expression in a noptr-new-declarator shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) and evaluate to a strictly positive value.

---

After some thoughts, next items should be relavant :

**8.3.4/1 [dcl.array]**, these parts :

> In a declaration T D where D has the form

```
    D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt
```

> and the type of the identiﬁer in the declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list T”, then the type of the identiﬁer of D is an array type;

and

> if the constant expression is omitted, the type of the identiﬁer of D is “derived-declarator-type- list array of unknown bound of T”, an incomplete object type.

**5.3.4/1** tells :

> This type shall be a complete object type, but not an abstract class type or array thereof

Since you omitted the array size, the type is not complete, and your program is not valid c++.

Comment: What about <expression> in the first line. The <constant-expression> is for multi-dimensional arrays. eg `x = new char[plop*5 /*expression */][10 /*const-expression*/][100 /* const-expression */]`

Comment: With a quick glance I can not see <expression> being empty but ?

Comment: @LokiAstari That is why I added what the *constant-expression* can be in edit : *Every constant-expression in a noptr-new-declarator shall be an integral constant expression*. Since it is omitted in the question, then it is not a standard c++, but a compiler extension. It's not an UB, since it compiles, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @VJovic: Since the program violates a syntax rule, a diagnostic is required; a compiler that doesn't issue a diagnostic is non-conforming.  But a conforming compiler *could* still accept it after issuing a diagnostic (a warning is sufficient).  Once it's accepted it, the program's behavior is undefined (because nothing in the Standard defines its behavior).

Comment: I have had a look at this quote before and it looks close enough but I had the same doubt as Loki, So the Q is what about the `[ expression ]` in first line, what does it represent.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If the compiler accepts the line (with a diagnostic) then is it not implementation defined behavior?

Comment: @LokiAstari: Only if it's a documented extension.  By issuing the diagnostic, the compiler has fulfilled its commitment to the standard.  ("Implementation defined" means that the implementation must document the behavior.)

Comment: @LokiAstari (to your 1st comment) But it also applies to expressions of type `x = new char[10 /*const-expression*/]`. If you omit the const-expression, you break 5.4.3/6. Am I right, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @VJovic: No. In this case `10` is an <expression> from the first line. The BNF grammar for the second line is recursive the `[<const-exp>]` and must be proceeded by a `<noptr-new-declarator>` which means it must be proceeded by `[<expr>]`

Comment: @LokiAstari In that case, the edit should be relevant, right?

Comment: @VJovic: I don;t believe so. This is a declaration for an atomatic (or static) storage duration object that is not using `new`. Which we all know must be constant at compile time. The new operator is allowed to have a runtime value `expr` as the first dimension in an array. The discussion here is if `expression` must evaluate to a number, we are are relatively sure it must but not 100% sure (the confusion being caused by MSVS compiling the code with an empty `expression`). But MSVC is not known for its adherence to the standard (though they are getting better).